# mapstruct conditonly create and nested object

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am working with mapstruct and having below problem -

I have a DTO parent :

```
{
     "parentId":1,
      "child":{
       "id":1,
       "name":"firstBorn" 
       }
}
```

this are the DTO and server classes :

```
 @Data
    public class ParentDTO {
        int parentId;
        ChildDto child; 
    } 
    @Data
    public class ChildDTO{
        int id;
        ChildDto child; 
    }
```

the POJO are :

```
@Data
public class Parent{
    int parentId;
    Child child; 
} 
@Data
public class Child{
    int parentId;
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

so I am using Mapstruct in order to map between those two :

```
@Mapper( unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
class ParentMapper {
  @Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "parentId", target = "child.parentid"), 
    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "child.name")

  })
  Parent map(ParentDto source);

}
```

I would like to create the instance child if and only if it exists in the parent, otherwise I would like it to be null , how can I achieve this goal?

the problem appear when the child in null

```
{
"parentId":123
}
```

Comment: What does it mean if and only if it exists in the parent? Are you talking if child is null in the ParentDto or something else? Can you provide an example of what exactly you would expect the mapping code to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method and put your logic inside

```
  /**
   *  If you are sure that the parentDto will never be NULL, you can remove the @NonNull annotation (lombok.NonNull)
   *  I use the AllArgsConstructor to create a new instance of Child,
   *  I pass null to id (I think you will generate the id when you will save the Child entity in the DB), if not, you can change it with parentDto.getChild().getId()
   */
  protected Child mapChild(@NonNull ParentDto parentDto) {
     return parentDto.getChild() != null ? new Child(parentDto.getParentId(), null, parentDto.getChild().getName()) : null;
  }
```

and then use it to map Child entity

```
@Mapping(target = "child", expression = "java(mapChild(source))")
abstract Parent map(ParentDto source);
```

so now the mapper will look like this:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class ParentMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "child", expression = "java(mapChild(source))")
  abstract Parent map(ParentDto source);

  protected Child mapChild(@NonNull ParentDto parentDto) {
     return parentDto.getChild() != null ? new Child(parentDto.getParentId(), null, parentDto.getChild().getName()) : null;
  }

}
```